# How can I force Master Render event to fire with partial rendering enabled?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have some code in the Render event of my Master page that needs to be run on every postback, as it's used to translate some of the HTML content. However, the event does not seem to trigger on postback when I'm using an UpdatePanel and a ScriptManager with partial rendering set to true. Can I force the event to fire, or can I run my code elsewhere to produce the same result?

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
{
    string originalContent = String.Empty;
    string translatedContent = String.Empty;

    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
    {
        using (HtmlTextWriter htw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw))
        {
            base.Render(htw);
            htw.Close();

            originalContent = sw.ToString();
        }
    }

    // Translate content:
    translatedContent = ApplyGlobalization(Page, originalContent);

    // Write updated HTML:
    writer.Write(translatedContent);
}
```

Comment: Every page contained within the UpdatePanel seems to have its Render event triggered. Why is this and why won't the Master Render do the same?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved the problem by creating my own UpdatePanel with Render overridden. I put the same code into that method, but had to make some changes to adjust to the translation method to accustom to the special output that the UpdatePanel creates on partial postback.